# Why do these two resistor networks measure differently?

Tags: resistors, simulation, packages

Why do these two resistor networks measure differently?

Aren't two 100k resistors in series supposed to be equivalent to a single 200k resistor?

These are being simulated with Circuit Wizard.

[image]

Comment: The only way they measure anything other than 200 kohms exactly is if your simulator includes some random errors in the resistor values or the meter reading. In which case you may have just got different random errors in the two simulations.

Comment: In the real world, parts have a *tolerance* - often 5% to 20%. Apparently, the simulator is reminding you of that fact.

Comment: And a 200k resistor should measure 200k. As I recall this is not the first time your simulator gave unexpected results...I think that should be a message to you about your simulator.

Comment: It is just some tiny rounding error. Don't get hung up on it.

Comment: I remember reading that SPICE inserts a very high value resistor to ground on every node to help convergence. If this simulator is doing this the two circuits would behave differently (it would also explain the first circuit not reading exactly 200k). OP can check this by reducing every resistor by a factor of 10 and seeing if the error scales by the same amount.

Comment: @Austin is correct. Each spice simulator includes a feature called "gshunt" which may be non-zero in your simulation. You should check its value. There's also "gmin" that goes across every PN junction; "cshunt" which is similar to "gshunt" except that it adds capacitance at every node instead of conductance; etc. Find out what your situation actually is. Some simulators default "gshunt=0" but not all of them do.

Answer (score 1):

200kohm resistor , with a 5% tolerance could read anything between

200,000 - (200,000*0.05)
and
200,000 + (200,000*0.05)

so 190k to 210k

Looks like your simulator is also simulating a random tolerance within the above range.

for the 100k it goes from

95k to 105k

Comment: Your numbers are off a bit. 0.005 is 0.5%.